# Get Text from id="countdowndate" into new Date via Javascript

Tags: javascript, countdownjs.js

Apologies i know this is likely to be vey simple for many but appreciate the help. Im creating a countdown based on code collected from various spots including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946188/countdown-timer-to-specific-time).

The text date in the HTML ID "countdowndate" will be updated dynamically elsewhere. What i'd like to is replace the date in var end = new Date('10/26/2023 4:00 PM'); with the date from id="countdown". Full code below and thank you.

```
<div class="gwd-page-content gwd-page-size">
          <!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
          <p id="countdown" class="gwd-p-1m9p"></p>
          <p id="countdowndate" class="gwd-p-hm4b">'10/26/2026 6:00 PM'</p>
        </div>
      </gwd-page>
    </gwd-pagedeck>
  </gwd-google-ad>
            <script>              

            var end = new Date('10/26/2023 4:00 PM');

            var _second = 1000;
            var _minute = _second * 60;
            var _hour = _minute * 60;
            var _day = _hour * 24;
            var timer;

            function showRemaining() {
              var now = new Date();
              var nowUTC = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate(), now.getUTCHours(), now.getUTCMinutes(), now.getUTCSeconds());
              var distance = end - nowUTC;
              if (distance < 0) {

                clearInterval(timer);
                document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'The Lottery Draw is Closed';

                return;
              }
              var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
              var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
              var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
              var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

              document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ' days ' + hours + ' hours ' + minutes + ' mins ' + seconds + ' secs';
            }

            timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
          </script>
```

Tried lots of things but really shooting in the dark as im no coder.

Comment: `const dateString = document.getElementById("countdowndate").textContent.replaceAll("'", "")`

Comment: @Phil - wrong field I think. OP want's date to be created from (what is empty in the above code) `countdown` field.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I'm just going by the question title

Comment: So what content is found the the `countdown` `<p>` element that you want to convert to a date then?

Comment: @Phil - oh, wow. Yeah - needs some clarity for sure. That conflicts with the problem statement.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I want the text '10/26/2026 6:00 PM' in id='coundowndate' to replace the text '10/26/2023 4:00 PM' within var end = new Date(....).